# effectively creating dictionary of dictionaries where the values are a list from an Excel file

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am reading a big table with multiple columns using `parse` command. Then, I would like to use the first and second columns as a nested key pair along with using the rest of columns as a value stored in a list. I have written a code snippet which does what I wish. I was wondering if this operation can be performed more efficiently.

```
import pandas as pd

#The data frame comes from an Excel sheet using df.parse
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Company": ["TechCorp", "Innovate Inc", "Green Solutions", "Future Dynamics"],
    "Product": ["TC100", "IN200", "GS300", "FD400"],
    "Production Cost": [10000, 15000, 12000, 18000],
    "Development Time": [6, 9, 8, 12],
    "Launch Year": [2023, 2024, 2023, 2025]
})
 nested_dict = {}
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            fleet = row['Company']
            engine = row['Product']
            values = row[['Production Cost', 'Development Time', 'Launch Year']].tolist()

            if fleet not in nested_dict:
                nested_dict[fleet] = {}
            nested_dict[fleet][engine] = values
        return nested_dict
```

My goal is to get the following structure.

```
{'TechCorp': {'TC100': [10000, 6, 2023]}, 'Innovate Inc': {'IN200': [15000, 9, 2024]}, 'Green Solutions': {'GS300': [12000, 8, 2023]}, 'Future Dynamics': {'FD400': [18000, 12, 2025]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slightly optimise your code by using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and deconstructing `df.values`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

nested_dict = defaultdict(dict)
for fleet, engine, *values in df.values:
    nested_dict[fleet][engine] = values
```

I added another engine from `TechCorp` to your data to prove the code:

```
df.loc[4] = ['TechCorp','TC200', 20000, 12, 2025]
```

Output for my sample data:

```
{
 'TechCorp': {'TC100': [10000, 6, 2023], 'TC200': [20000, 12, 2025]},
 'Innovate Inc': {'IN200': [15000, 9, 2024]},
 'Green Solutions': {'GS300': [12000, 8, 2023]},
 'Future Dynamics': {'FD400': [18000, 12, 2025]}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) we can transform the dict to dict like `{column -> [values]}`:

```
df_dict = df.set_index(["Company", "Product"]).T.to_dict(orient='list')
```

#### Output :

```
{('TechCorp', 'TC100'): [10000, 6, 2023],  ('Innovate Inc', 'IN200'): [15000, 9, 2024],  ('Green Solutions', 'GS300'): [12000, 8, 2023],  ('Future Dynamics', 'FD400'): [18000, 12, 2025]}
```

Then we can use a loop to get the desired output :

```
nested_dict = {
    fleet: {engine: values}
    for (fleet, engine), values in dict_1.items()
}
nested_dict
```

#### Output :

```
{'TechCorp': {'TC100': [10000, 6, 2023]},
 'Innovate Inc': {'IN200': [15000, 9, 2024]},
 'Green Solutions': {'GS300': [12000, 8, 2023]},
 'Future Dynamics': {'FD400': [18000, 12, 2025]}}
```